# 500 internal server error after cache clear in prestashop

Tags: prestashop, http-status-code-500

After turning off cache and clearing it on my prestashop store im gettin 500 internal server error. When im turning on error reporting, im getting error like this:

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/cache/prod/appParameters.php' (include_path='/vendor/pear/pear_exception:/vendor/pear/console_getopt:/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src:/vendor/pear/archive_tar:.:/:/usr/local/php56/lib/pear') in /config/bootstrap.php on line 86
```

But when i turn on debug mode, store is loading copletely.

Where could be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably a permissions issue. Folders should have 755 and files 644. If this doesn't solve it, change the owner of the folder(s) and files. You will need to do some guessing here to set the proper owner. It depends on your server (Apache and PHP) configuration. Maybe you can ask your hosting provider for details.